# Get certificate and user information in WCF service

Tags: wcf, .net-4.5

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS. Clients communicating with the service must have one of our company's client certificates. The service uses the certificate to identify the client and handle access.

Now I also want the clients to authenticate using username and password, as and extra security layer with a sort of two-factor authentication. The user credentials will be used together with the certificate to identify the client to handle access.

I was hoping the only thing I needed to do was to send the user credentials from the client, but I don't know how to get them in the service.

**Working code using only certificates:**

```
var x509ClaimSet = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.ClaimSets.FirstOrDefault() as X509CertificateClaimSet;
if (x509ClaimSet == null || x509ClaimSet.X509Certificate == null)
    throw AccessDeniedException();

// throws AccessDeniedException if no client can be found
var clientId = GetClientId(x509ClaimSet.X509Certificate);
```

Now I'm trying to send the user credentials from the client using:

```
var client = new ServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Foo";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Bar";
```

How do I get this UserName and Password in the service?

The current service configuration is:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="64343ee2c8338518e78ba698f3936dc92c90db57" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding" contract="IService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```